how to showing TolistAsync() while using NAPS2.sdk package
I am trying to create sdk scanning using NAPS2 package.
i already installed naps2 sdk, microsoft entity framework in my project.
however, when i try to write code as below:
var images = await controller.Scan(options).ToListAsync();
ToListAsync is not showing.
Here's the original codes:
// scan and save pdf
var images = await controller.Scan(options).ToListAsync();
var pdfExporter = new PdfExporter(scanningContext);
await pdfExporter.Export("Doc.Pdf", images);


ToListAsync is extension method on IQueryable, as can be seen in the documentation.
And from what I can see in NAPS2 examples, controller.Scan method returns IAsyncEnumerable<ProcessedImage> (or the docs for Scan method), which does not have method ToListAsync. That is why it is not showing up.
To correctly use that method and leverage asynchronous execution, we can simply follow the example with await foreach, where getting each item of collection is asynchronous action. So to convert it into regular List you need:
var images = new List<ProcessedImage>();

await foreach (var i in controller.Scan(options))
{
    images.Add(img);
}


million thanks for your respons, I will try it
